# Processing JSON data in javascript

Tags: json

i'm trying to be able to handle this json .. someone please help me, thanks!

I have json

```
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: '1608109604806',
    value: '42'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608127592082',
    value: '4'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608138383730',
    value: '421'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608141916521',
    value: '14'
  },
];
```

I want to get results like this
`[1608109604806, 1608127592082, 1608138383730, 1608141916521]`

Comment: `data.map(d => d.timestamp)` ?

Comment: this is object and for convert it to json you should use JSON.stringify

Comment: Please mention language you are working in also your work to solve this problem , you need to understand that no one here can read minds so you have to mention all the things that are required to solve your query , also show some efforts

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is what you are looking for.
To quote the documentation:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Basically, it runs the function `item.timestamp` once for each element in your json document. `item.timestamp` is then added to a new array (which `map()` automatically makes).

`map()` then returns the new array with the information inside of it

```
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: '1608109604806',
    value: '42'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608127592082',
    value: '4'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608138383730',
    value: '421'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608141916521',
    value: '14'
  },
];

var result = data.map((item) => { 
    item.timestamp 
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Assuming you want to read timestamp value and convert the same into Number datatype:

  var data = [
  {
    timestamp: '1608109604806',
    value: '42'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608127592082',
    value: '4'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608138383730',
    value: '421'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '1608141916521',
    value: '14'
  },
];

var temp=[];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  temp[i]=Number(data[i].timestamp);
}
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: another assumption : Codding language

Comment: @kelvin - you didn't specify what language you are using. Most people will assume javascript